# What is the difference between a 14" Viola and a 4/4 Violin?

Tags: violin, viola, violin-family

What is the difference between a 14" Viola and a 4/4 Violin? Are they both the same but just different names? Is there any difference in standard tuning or strings used? Or any difference in instrument body specifications?

Comment: String instrument sizes are far from standardized, especially violas seems to have a broad length range. The question seems covered in the duplicate question given.

Comment: covered in the duplicate question, but to summarize: generally no difference other than strings and setup, with some manufacturers making the viola body a little deeper than the violin.

Comment: Yes, 14" means full size.  But when I posted an answer to that effect, it got voted down.  So I'll tell you the same thing in a comment!

Answer (score 4):

The rib height on a 14" Viola is bigger.

Here is a short YouTube video on the matter:

Comment: Aren't they also tuned differently?

Comment: Yes, they are tuned differently. A fifth lower than the violin. The viola tuning from high to low: A-D-G-C. Note that on the video the guy tells that the bridge on the viola needs to be cut slightly different, compared with violin, because of the lower strings. It is the C-string that needs "freedom" to vibrate so to speak.

Comment: I wondered because the question specifically asks about tuning.

Comment: Oh yes, tuning was included. Then I think the question is covered. Summary: 1) A 14" viola has a higher or wider rib than a full size violin. 2) It is tuned a fifth lower than the violin. 3) The bridge is slightly different cut.